# Is there any way in Kotlin to jump out of a function from another function?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, label

Is there any way in kotlin using labels or any kind of feature so that we can jump out of the main function from the calling function.
What i want is when i return from jumperFunction i want to jump out of both the functions.

```
fun mainFunction(){
// some code and calling this function
jumperFunction()
}

fun jumperFunction{
// some code
return@mainFunction
}
```

Comment: doesn't it a usual function behavior?

Comment: I thought there will be some way to handle this scenario, like using labels or something.

Comment: The only way to control the flow directly from a called function is through exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Have `jumperFunction()` return a Boolean, and use that result:

```
fun mainFunction() {
    //...
    if (!jumperFunction()) return
    //...
}

//returns false if the calling function should return
fun jumperFunction(): Boolean {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your use case, but you can have [non-local returns with inlined lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns).

Example:

```
fun main() {
    baz {
        println("Inside lambda")
        return
    }
}

inline fun baz(block: () -> Unit) {
    println("[Baz] Before block")
    block()
    println("[Baz] After block")
}
```

Will print:

```
[Baz] Before block

Inside lambda
```

Note that it skips `[Baz] After block`